# ¿Cómo sumar solo los números primos de un array con javascript?

Tags: javascript, array, números-primos

Quisiera saber como podría sumar los número primos de este array y que me retorne el resultado de dicha suma (pero solo de los números primos). Tomando en cuenta que el array se va a recibir como parámetro y probar que funciona el siguiente array: `[1, 5, 2, 9, 3, 4, 11]` devuelve 21. Muchas gracias.

```
function sumaTodosPrimos(array) {
      
    var arrayEnteros = []; 
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] % 2 === 0) { 
            arrayEnteros.push(array[i]); 
        }
    }
    // return true;

    var suma = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayEnteros.length; i++) {
        suma = suma + arrayEnteros[i]; 
    }

    return suma;

}
console.log(sumaTodosPrimos([1,5,2,9,3,4,11]));
```

Comment: ¿Con qué lenguaje estás trabajando? Recuerda que es importante mencionarlo. Puedes editar tu pregunta para agregar esa información.

Comment: con javascript, gracias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes separar la lógica en dos partes:

- Saber si el número es primo
- Sumar el número si es primo

Por lo que el código sería así:

```js
function esPrimo(num) {
  for(var i = 2; i < num; i++)
    if(num % i === 0) return false;
  return num > 1;
}

function sumaTodosPrimos(array) {
  return array.reduce((acumulado, numero) => {
    if (esPrimo(numero)) {
      acumulado += numero;
    }
    return acumulado
  }, 0);
}

console.log(sumaTodosPrimos([1,5,2,9,3,4,11]));
```

Se hace uso de [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/reduce) para ayudar con el proceso de suma, se recorre cada uno de los números en el array y si se trata de un número primo, entonces se suma al acumulado que empieza en 0. Si el número en cuestión no es un número primo, simplemente se ignora.

Comment: muchas gracias Ricardo !!!

Comment: Por nada, recuerda que si alguna de las respuestas te es de utilidad puedes [votarla o marcarla como correcta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Al poner esta condición:

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] % 2 === 0) { 
        arrayEnteros.push(array[i]); 
    }
}
```

Y siendo tu array el array de entrada con los números que tienes que averiguar si son primos o no, lo que estás haciendo es recoger **números pares**, ya que estás imponiendo la condición de que el número en cuestión sea divisible entre 2 (de resto cero).

```js
var entrada = [1, 5, 2, 9, 3, 4, 11];
var n = entrada.length;

var primos = [];
for(var i=0;i<n;i++){
  if(esPrimo(entrada[i])){
    primos.push(entrada[i]);
  }
}

//AQUÍ HACES LA SUMA:
var suma = 0;
primos.forEach (function(numero){
  suma += numero;
});

document.getElementById('suma').innerHTML = suma;


function esPrimo(numero){
  if(numero == 1){
    return false;
  }

  for(var i=1;i<numero;i++){
    if(numero % i == 0 && i!=1){
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

```html
<p>La suma vale <span id="suma"></span></p>
```