# numeros primos javascript

Tags: javascript

function sumaTodosPrimos(array) {

// La funcion llamada 'sumaTodosPrimos' recibe como argumento un array de enteros.
// y debe devolver la suma total entre todos los numeros que sean primos.
// Pista: un número primo solo es divisible por sí mismo y por 1
// Nota: Los números 0 y 1 NO son considerados números primos
// Ej:
// sumaTodosPrimos([1, 5, 2, 9, 3, 4, 11]) devuelve 5 + 2 + 3 + 11 = 21

necesito ayuda. Gracias

Comment: Te recomiendo leas [ask], ¿necesitas ayuda con qué?

Comment: que haz intentado? donde tienes el codigo? puedes buscar en internet muchos ejemplos

Comment: Hola, consulta [R: Números primos en javascript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/327338/91033) sólo necesitas generar los primos hasta el mayor de los números dados y verificar cuales lo son y sumarlos. **En general es útil consultar qué preguntas y respuestas existen** antes de hacer una pregunta sin mostrar haber intentado algo.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cómo sumar solo los números primos de un array con javascript?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/414024/c%c3%b3mo-sumar-solo-los-n%c3%bameros-primos-de-un-array-con-javascript). De hecho se usa el mismo ejemplo por lo que he de suponer que es exactamente el mismo ejercicio.

Answer (score 0):

Mirate el operador 'Resto o Residuo  (%)'
Con el podrás comprobar el resultado de la división

la condicion ya la sabes, que sea divisible entre 1 y entre si mismo...