# Identificar números primo y luego sumarlos

Tags: javascript

```
function sumaTodosPrimos(array) {
```

// La funcion llamada 'sumaTodosPrimos' recibe como argumento un array de enteros.

// y debe devolver la suma total entre todos los numeros que sean primos.

// Pista: un número primo solo es divisible por sí mismo y por 1

// Nota: Los números 0 y 1 NO son considerados números primos

// Ej:

// sumaTodosPrimos([1, 5, 2, 9, 3, 4, 11]) devuelve 5 + 2 + 3 + 11 = 21

// Tu código aca:

```
if( array < 2) return false;
  if(array === 2) return true;
  for(var i = 2; i < array; i++) {
    if(array % i === 0) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;


var suma = 0;
if (array === true) {

 for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)

    {suma = suma + array[i];  }
 
}
  
 return suma;
}
```

Eso es lo que hice.
Este es el error que me sale en el test:

```
● Funciones › sumaTodosPrimos › should return 23 with [0,5,7,10,11,15,20]

    expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

    Expected: 23
    Received: true

      78 |     });
      79 |     it('should return 23 with [0,5,7,10,11,15,20]', function() {
    > 80 |       expect(sumaTodosPrimos([0,5,7,10,11,15,20])).toBe(23);
         |                                                    ^
      81 |     });
      82 |     it('should return 35 with [-2,5,7,10,23,10,25]', function() {
      83 |       expect(sumaTodosPrimos([-2,5,7,10,23,10,25])).toBe(35);

      at Object.<anonymous> (tests/checkpoint.test.js:80:52)

  ● Funciones › sumaTodosPrimos › should return 35 with [-2,5,7,10,23,10,25]

    expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

    Expected: 35
    Received: true

      81 |     });
      82 |     it('should return 35 with [-2,5,7,10,23,10,25]', function() {
    > 83 |       expect(sumaTodosPrimos([-2,5,7,10,23,10,25])).toBe(35);
         |                                                     ^
      84 |     });
      85 |   });
      86 |
```

Comment: Cuál es el error?

Comment: El ejercicio va con un test y el test me dice undefined

Comment: Puedes agregar el error en la pregunta? Así se entendería mejor y puedes recibir una solución.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cómo sumar solo los números primos de un array con javascript?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/414024/c%c3%b3mo-sumar-solo-los-n%c3%bameros-primos-de-un-array-con-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que estas un poco confundido, en la función estas recibiendo un arreglo y en el código en la primer linea lo tratas como un entero **if( array < 2) return false;** esto siempre te va a regresar false (además de otros errores en el código). Supongo que tu test espera un numero y tu le regresas un booleano.

Puedes ver el código que hice para que te des una idea de como debería ser.

```js
function sumaTodosPrimos(array){
  let suma = 0;
  for(i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    if(esPrimo(array[i])){
      suma += array[i];
    }
  }
  return suma;
}

function esPrimo(n){
    if (n <= 1) {return false;}
     for (k = 2; k < n; k++) {
            if( n % k == 0){
                return false;
            }
      }
      return true;
}

var arreglo = [1, 5, 2, 9, 3, 4, 11];
document.write("La suma de primos es " + sumaTodosPrimos(arreglo))
```

Comment: No lo valida el test

Comment: El error que tira el test es igual al que subí. Seguramente pide que se haga de una forma en especifica.